# mail is not sending to respective user in java

Tags: html, servlets, netbeans, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail to respective user who upload file. I have one **process.jsp** page, in that user will enter mail id and when user click on send  then mail will be sent as file is uploaded. I have written code for sending mail but it's giving error like **There were an error: null**. File is uploading into MySQL database successfully but mail is not sending.

This is my process.jsp page

```html
<form action="SendMailAttachServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="email" name="mailid" value="" required="" size="60" placeholder="Please enter your mail address" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  <table>

    <tr style="display:none">
      <td>Subject </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="subject" size="50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none">
      <td>Content </td>
      <td><textarea rows="10" cols="39" name="content"></textarea> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**Note:- I want only two fields i.e. one Textfield for mail id and another one for send button. I don't want Subject and Content fields**

This is my EmailUtility.java page

```js
package com.codejava.email;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class EmailUtility {
  /**
   * Sends an e-mail message from a SMTP host with a list of attached files.
   *
   */
  public static void sendEmailWithAttachment(String host, String port,
    final String userName, final String password, String toAddress
  )
  throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    // sets SMTP server properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.user", userName);
    properties.put("mail.password", password);

    // creates a new session with an authenticator
    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
      public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
      }
    };
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

    // creates a new e-mail message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
    InternetAddress[] toAddresses = {
      new InternetAddress(toAddress)
    };
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
    // msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());

    // creates message part
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    //  messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");

    // creates multi-part
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


    // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
    msg.setContent(multipart);

    // sends the e-mail
    Transport.send(msg);
  }

}
```

This is my SendMailAttachServlet.java file

```js
package com.codejava.email;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/SendMailAttachServlet")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 2, // 2MB
  maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10, // 10MB
  maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50) // 50MB
public class SendMailAttachServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private String host;
  private String port;
  private String user;
  private String pass;

  public void init() {
    // reads SMTP server setting from web.xml file
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    host = context.getInitParameter("host");
    port = context.getInitParameter("port");
    user = context.getInitParameter("user");
    pass = context.getInitParameter("pass");
  }


  /**
   * handles form submission
   */
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //  List<File> uploadedFiles = saveUploadedFiles(request);

    String recipient = request.getParameter("recipient");
    //   String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
    //   String content = request.getParameter("content");

    String resultMessage = "";

    try {
      EmailUtility.sendEmailWithAttachment(host, port, user, pass,
        recipient);

      resultMessage = "The e-mail was sent successfully";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      resultMessage = "There were an error: " + ex.getMessage();
    } finally {
      //deleteUploadFiles(uploadedFiles);
      request.setAttribute("message", resultMessage);
      getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(
        request, response);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Saves files uploaded from the client and return a list of these files
   * which will be attached to the e-mail message.
   */



}
```

Comment: please help me with this..

Comment: `<input type="email" name="mailid" ... />` vs `String recipient = request.getParameter("recipient");` - do you see it now?

Comment: @Jozef Chocholacek Thanks for the reply. I understood mistake which is done in code. Now I am getting error like this when I  enter mail id and clicked on send then I got this error   "There were an error: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form action="SendMailAttachServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="email" name="mailid" value="" required="" size="60" placeholder="Please enter your mail address" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Now **servlet** code:

```
package com.codejava.email;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/SendMailAttachServlet")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 2, // 2MB
  maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10, // 10MB
  maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50) // 50MB
public class SendMailAttachServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private String host;
  private String port;
  private String user;
  private String pass;

  public void init() {
    // reads SMTP server setting from web.xml file
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    host = context.getInitParameter("host");
    port = context.getInitParameter("port");
    user = context.getInitParameter("user");
    pass = context.getInitParameter("pass");
  }


  /**
   * handles form submission
   */
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //  List<File> uploadedFiles = saveUploadedFiles(request);

    String recipient = request.getParameter("mailid");//here you have to give the same name as your HTML name filed  or input filed have

    String resultMessage = "";

    try {
      EmailUtility.sendEmailWithAttachment(host, port, user, pass,
        recipient);

      resultMessage = "The e-mail was sent successfully";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      resultMessage = "There were an error: " + ex.getMessage();
    } finally {
      //deleteUploadFiles(uploadedFiles);
      request.setAttribute("message", resultMessage);
      getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(
        request, response);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Saves files uploaded from the client and return a list of these files
   * which will be attached to the e-mail message.
   */



}
```

This is my `web.xml` file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

  <display-name>EmailAttachWebApp</display-name>

  <!-- SMTP settings -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>host</param-name>
    <param-value>smtp.gmail.com</param-value>
  </context-param>



  <context-param>
    <param-name>port</param-name>
    <param-value>465</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>user</param-name>
    <param-value>dhanbashital@gmail.com</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>pass</param-name>
    <param-value>password</param-value>
  </context-param>


  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
      30
    </session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understood mistake which is done in code. Now I am getting error like this when I  enter mail id and clicked on send then I got this error   "There were an error: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1"

Comment: "mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"
 "mail.smtp.port", "587"

Comment: can you share me your web.xml file

Comment: Please check above web.xml file I have shared.

Comment: try with different port and please check your email setting for accessible via localhost to send mail

Comment: I tried these ports 465, 25, 587 and I also turned on "access to less secure apps" in gmail. but also getting the same error

Comment: I restarted apache, done with clean and build option but also getting same error. Please help. I am taking reference from this link "https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/jsp/send-attachments-with-e-mail-using-jsp-servlet-and-javamail#EmailUtility"

Comment: Email me your project or share github link